# Oculta campo do select mysql

Tags: mysql

Bom estou acostumado a fazer o select da seguinte forma:

```
select nome, idade,cidade from cadastro
```

Esse select me retorna os campos nome, idade,cidade.

Porém quero fazer ao contrário, tenho uma tabela com muitos campos e quero que o select me retorne todos os campos, menos os campos `nome` e `idade`.

É possível fazer isso?

Comment: Acho que você terá que discriminar os campos, exceto estes 2 ai na query.

Comment: Isso eu sei, porém quero saber se existe uma forma mais simples. Pois eu iria discriminar apenas 2 campos que eu não queria ao invés de ter que descriminar todos os campos.

Answer (score 2):

Precisa de permissões, não existe um comando especifico mas dá para fazer assim:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), 
'<colunas_omitidas>,', '') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<table>' 
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '<database>'), ' FROM <table>');

    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Trocando `<table>`, `<database>` e `<colunas_omitidas>`

Faço muito no trabalho porque tem tabelas com mais de 60 colunas

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível fazer isto porque não existe um **modifier** com esta funcionalidade previsto no `SELECT`, pelo menos não até a versão 5.7:

```
SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
      [PARTITION partition_list]
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
    [HAVING where_condition]
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
    [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
    [PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
    [INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'
        [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
        export_options
      | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
      | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
    [FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]
```

Referência: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html